# Angular: Validators dependents

Tags: angular, validation

I'm at beginning way as Angular dev. 
I try to Create simple form where some of de inputs field's are depend of others.
Here my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="betingForkForm" novalidate>

<fieldset formGroupName="requredField">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
                'correct':startingValue.valid  && (startingValue.touched || startingValue.dirty),
                'incorrect':startingValue.invalid  && (startingValue.touched || startingValue.dirty)}">
        <label>Starting value in units</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="startingValue">
        <div class="form-control-feedback"
        *ngIf="startingValue.invalid && (startingValue.touched || startingValue.dirty)">
            <p>Starting value is required.</p>
        </div>
        <pre>Valid? {{ startingValue.valid }} </pre>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
            'correct':expectedValue.valid && (expectedValue.touched || expectedValue.dirty),
            'incorrect':expectedValue.invalid && (expectedValue.touched || expectedValue.dirty)}">
        <label>Expected value</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="expectedValue">
        <div class="form-control-feedback"
            *ngIf="expectedValue.invalid && (expectedValue.touched || expectedValue.dirty)">
            <p>Expected value is requred.</p>
        </div>
        <pre>Valid? {{ expectedValue.valid }} </pre>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
    'correct':minProbability.valid,
    'incorrect':minProbability.invalid}">
    <label>Min probability per combination</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="minProbability">
    <pre>Valid? {{ minProbability.valid }} </pre>
</div>

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
    'correct':minProfit.valid,
    'incorrect':minProfit.invalid}">
    <label>Min profit per unit to combination</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="minProfit">
    <pre>Valid? {{ minProfit.valid }} </pre>
</div>
<button type="submit" name>Add Fork</button>
```

Here ts component code:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-create-betting-form',
  templateUrl: './create-betting-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-betting-form.component.css']
})
export class CreateBettingFormComponent implements OnInit {

  betingForkForm: FormGroup;
  startingValue: FormControl;
  expectedValue: FormControl;
  minProbability: FormControl;
  minProfit: FormControl;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }

  createFormControls() {
    this.startingValue = new FormControl('Starting value',
      [Validators.required, Validators.min(2) , Validators.max(100000)]);
    this.expectedValue = new FormControl('Expected value',
                        [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.startingValue.value), Validators.max(100000)]);
    this.minProbability =  new FormControl('Min probability');
    this.minProfit = new FormControl('Min profit');
  }

  createForm() {
    this.betingForkForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormGroup({
        startingValue: this.startingValue,
        expectedValue: this.expectedValue
      }),
      minProbability: this.minProbability,
      minProfit: this.minProfit
    });
  }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1) Why wen I pass bigger number then 100000 still I have Valid properties (in HTML template) set as True in two firs inputs.
2) When I pass the smallest number to the second input still prop is valid.
3) My [ngClass]  doesn't take expected style according to first two fieldsets (in CSS all classes are fine)

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No, no error. I added prop in button [disabled]="betingForkForm.invalid, but as I supposed it won't solve my problem, because it only prevents to submit an invalid form. Validation on real-time will be still incorrect.

Comment: I got only that what I present + additional Css styles.  Where I can find that requredField in FormGroup, Validators and FormControl classes I can't find this.

Comment: Ok fine in stackblitz everything is great but when I started ng serve on my PC, the borders on two firs inputs did not apply. Also, my validate condition in the second input - Validators.min(this.startingValue.value) did not behave as I expect. I want it invalid wheen I pass number less than in first input or greater than 100000.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-twh3wz. Now I see the main difference between our stackblitz. Why You create FormBuilder inside hello.component and bunch of others stuff? It is the main reason why my app doesn't work?

Comment: Ok fine. That is one problem. But still, my app works only in StackBlitz template, on my PC not. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://github.com/tbl4h/BookAppV0.2 here is my repo on Github.

Comment: you had typo in html template  formGroupName="requiredField" 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tudrcu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem creating special method witch monitor/subscribe events from HTML inputs as below:

```
  onSubscribe() {
this.startingValue.valueChanges.subscribe(changed => {
  if (changed) {
    this.betingForkForm.get('requiredField').get('expectedValue').setValidators(
      [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.startingValue.value), Validators.max(100000)]);
    this.betingForkForm.get('requiredField').get('expectedValue').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
this.expectedValue.valueChanges.subscribe(changed => {
  if (changed) {
    this.betingForkForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your code you have to disable the button using the disabled property in the HTML template. In order to do this, first, you have to give the form a variable and assign it the ngForm directive.

So first you give the form a variable, say "form".

```
<form [formGroup]="betingForkForm" novalidate #form="ngForm">
```

Then you have to use this variable with the submit button, using the disable property.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" name>Add Fork</button>
```

I hope this helps :)